# Right way of using transaction scope with Devart Connectory Mysql

Tags: c#, mysql, distributed-transactions

We have been using C# and mysql with .net connector but with individual commit where at times it fail to commit all. So we are now moving to this tool http://www.devart.com/dotconnect/mysql/ which supports distributed transaction. All works fine just that we are not too sure how to put the multiple connection. Method 1 is nesting each of the connection into one another. Method 2 is separately. Where we should be closing the connection or is handled by the transScope.Complete(); and transScope.Dispose();

Method 1.

```
using (TransactionScope transScope = new TransactionScope())
{
     string myConnStringLocal = "User Id=***;Password=****;Host=" + globalSettings.settingLocalIP + ";Database=" + globalSettings.settingLocalDB;
     using (MySqlConnection connectionLocal = new MySqlConnection(myConnStringLocal))
     {
       connectionLocal.open() 

       string myConnStringCentral = "User Id=***;Password=*****;Host=" + globalSettings.settingCentralIP + ";Database=" + globalSettings.settingCentralDB;
         using (MySqlConnection connectionCentral = new MySqlConnection(myConnStringCentral))
         {
             connectionCentral.Open();
               string myConnStringCentralCopy = "User Id=*****;Password=*****;Host=" + globalSettings.settingCentralCopyIP + ";Database=" + globalSettings.settingCentralCopyDB;
              using (MySqlConnection connectionCentralCopy = new MySqlConnection(myConnStringCentralCopy))
             {
                 connectionCentralCopy.Open();   
             }
         }
     }

     if (rollbackBoolean == 0)
        transScope.Complete();
     else
        transScope.Dispose();
}
```

Method 2

```
using (TransactionScope transScope = new TransactionScope())
{
     string myConnStringLocal = "User Id=***;Password=****;Host=" + globalSettings.settingLocalIP + ";Database=" + globalSettings.settingLocalDB;
     using (MySqlConnection connectionLocal = new MySqlConnection(myConnStringLocal))
     {
         connectionLocal.open() 
     }

     string myConnStringCentral = "User Id=***;Password=*****;Host=" + globalSettings.settingCentralIP + ";Database=" + globalSettings.settingCentralDB;
    using (MySqlConnection connectionCentral = new MySqlConnection(myConnStringCentral))
    {
       connectionCentral.Open();
    }

    string myConnStringCentralCopy = "User Id=*****;Password=*****;Host=" + globalSettings.settingCentralCopyIP + ";Database=" + globalSettings.settingCentralCopyDB;
    using (MySqlConnection connectionCentralCopy = new MySqlConnection(myConnStringCentralCopy))
    {
        connectionCentralCopy.Open();   
    }

    if (rollbackBoolean == 0)
        transScope.Complete();
    else
        transScope.Dispose();
}
```

Comment: Why do you want to open 3 connections to same DB? Connection is not closed by `TransactionScope`. You dont have to call `trasnsactionScope.Dispose()` - the `using` statement does that for you.

Comment: Distributed transaction is a overhead and would be a big hurdle if you want to scale your app. Avoid it as much as possible.

Comment: @YK1 no is three different dbs 1.globalSettings.settingLocalDB 2.globalSettings.settingCentralDB and 3.globalSettings.settingCentralCopyDB. I know is tedious but I got no choice since I got update data on the spot else there will incositency view. So which method to use 1 or 2? How to close the db connection after the transactionscope is it?

Comment: I see, i think both methods are equivalent. Connection is closed by `using` statement block around the connection objects.

Comment: @YK1 I dont get you on how to use "using" method to close the connection ? Any example on it please? Besides that when I start the using for the connection where should I be putting the catches?

Comment: When you apply `using` statement to an object which implements `IDisposable`, it will call that object's `Dispose` method when the `using` block ends. In your case, when the object is the connection, the `Dispose` method will close the connection - so you don't have explicitly call `Close()` on your connection. See complete example  here - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.transactions.transactionscope.aspx

Comment: @I went through it meaning in my case the transactionScope will close it when I call the complete rite. Another thing in each of my connection I keep track of try and catch and if there is any error I flagged the rollbackBoolean to 1 so then it wont complete and whole transaction should be rollbacked is that a correct mechanism?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both methods are correct. TransactionScope will be used together with dotConnect for MySQL in both cases. The following code is not required:

```
else
transScope.Dispose();
```

because the Dispose method is called automatically when exiting the `using (TransactionScope transScope = new TransactionScope())` block.

*... I went through it meaning in my case the transactionScope will close it when I call the complete rite...*

No, the transScope.Complete() does not close the connection. If the connection is closed inside the using block for TransactionScope, the connection object will be closed, however the internal connection will stay open for sending changes to the database when calling transScope.Dispose() if it is preceeded by the transScope.Complete() call. transScope.Dispose() closes the internal connection if the Close or Dispose method was called for the connection object. If the connection object was not closed, transScope.Dispose() does nothing to the connection.

*... Another thing in each of my connection I keep track of try and catch and if there is any error I flagged the rollbackBoolean to 1 so then it wont complete and whole transaction should be rollbacked is that a correct mechanism? ...*

If an error occurred, just don't call Complete. If the Complete method was not called, the transaction will be rolled back when executing the Dispose method.

Here is the example with a try/catch block and rolling back the transaction in case of error:

```
using (TransactionScope transScope = new TransactionScope())
{
   try
   {
      string myConnStringLocal = "User Id=***;Password=****;Host=" + globalSettings.settingLocalIP + ";Database=" + globalSettings.settingLocalDB;
      using (MySqlConnection connectionLocal = new MySqlConnection(myConnStringLocal))
      {
         connectionLocal.Open();
      }

      string myConnStringCentral = "User Id=***;Password=*****;Host=" + globalSettings.settingCentralIP + ";Database=" + globalSettings.settingCentralDB;
      using (MySqlConnection connectionCentral = new MySqlConnection(myConnStringCentral))
      {
         connectionCentral.Open();
      }
      string myConnStringCentralCopy = "User Id=*****;Password=*****;Host=" + globalSettings.settingCentralCopyIP + ";Database=" + globalSettings.settingCentralCopyDB;
      using (MySqlConnection connectionCentralCopy = new MySqlConnection(myConnStringCentralCopy))
      {
         connectionCentralCopy.Open();
      }
      transScope.Complete();
      Console.WriteLine("Transaction is completed");
   }
   catch (Exception)
   {
      Console.WriteLine("Transaction is rolled back");
   }
}
```

Comment: so I guess you are the from the company itself. The problem is that in my first connectionLocal  I also perform some select to check if the values are below certain range then I want the whole thing to be rollback that is why I keep track of the rollbackBoolean value. So in normal instance can I assume that once its our from the TransactionScop all the internal connection will be closed? I am confuse here "If the connection object was not closed, transScope.Dispose() does nothing to the connection." So must I calls the close or not?

Comment: transScope.Complete(); and transScope.Dispose(); do not close connections, and you have to take care about it yourself.

Comment: @Can I close the connection say based on your example I have the try and catch and can I have in the finally close all the 3 db connections will that be right?

Comment: When you leave the using block (even if you leave it because of an exception), the Dispose method is called for the object. I.e. if an exception occurs inside the block `using (MySqlConnection connectionLocal`, connectionLocal.Dispose will be called and the catch block execution will start. For more information, please refer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36081/how-to-catch-an-exception-in-a-using-block-with-net-2-0
You cannot access the connections from the finally block because they are unavailable outside of their using blocks.

Comment: @I am kind of confuse here when you say that once you leave the using block the connectionLocal.Dispose is called then how does this work transScope.Complete(); if the connection are closed ready?

Comment: If the connection is closed inside the using block for TransactionScope, the connection object will be closed, however the internal connection will stay open for sending changes to the database when calling transScope.Dispose() if it is preceeded by the transScope.Complete() call.